# PHP does not set the FOREIGN key

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Good day,

I am facing a riddle, I want to import the following via PHP on the database.

```php
$sql = "
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `whtsdg_field_products` 
  ( 
    `whtsdg_field_products_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `whtsdg_field_list_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `product_number` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (whtsdg_field_products_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (whtsdg_field_list_id) REFERENCES whtsdg_field_list (whtsdg_field_list_id)
  );";

$db->executeQuery($sql);
```

It all works so far only he just does not set me the FK and I do not know why.
If I enter the code in the MySQL so, everything works without problem.
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or where the error lies?

EDIT: I checked the Tables with the "SELECT table_name, table_schema FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine = 'InnoDB'" so from this the storage engine seems to be InnoDB.
The schema for my tables are:

whtsdg_config_list

whtsdg_config_list_id int(11) noNULL noStandard AUTO_INCREMENT Primarykey Unique
whtsdg_fiel_list_id int(11) noNULL noStandard >supposed to be a FK< Unique
whtsdg_fiel_config_id int(11) noNULL noStandard >supposed to be a FK< Unique
created_at timestamp attribute="on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" NULLallowd standard=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP extra="ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"

whtsdg_field_config

whtsdg_field_config_id int(11) noNUL noStandard AUTO_INCREMENT Primarykey Unique
name varchar(255)utf8_general_ci noNULL noStandard
config json noNULL noStandard
created_at timestamp attribute="on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" NULLallowd standard=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP extra="ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"

whtsdg_field_list

whtsdg_field_list_id int(11) noNUL noStandard AUTO_INCREMENT Primarykey Unique
Setname varchar(255)utf8_general_ci noNULL noStandard
created_at timestamp attribute="on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" NULLallowd standard=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP extra="ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"

whtsdg_field_proudcts

whtsdg_field_proudcts_id int(11) noNUL noStandard AUTO_INCREMENT Primarykey Unique
whtsdg_field_list_id int(11) noNULL noStandard >supposed to be a FK< Unique
product_number varchar(255)utf8_general_ci noNULL noStandard
created_at timestamp attribute="on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" NULLallowd standard=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP extra="ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"

Comment: If "you aren't allowed", there should be an error message. You might also have to post the schema for `whtsdg_field_list`

Comment: Which storage engine are you using? Only inndoDB and NDB Cluster support foreign keys.

Comment: Is there any error message given? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: It looks like you have a data type mismatch. `whtsdg_field_list_id int(11) noNUL noStandard AUTO_INCREMENT Primarykey` is apparently not `UNISGNED` but your new table's column is `whtsdg_field_list_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL`. The data types of the FK and its reference column must match exactly.

Comment: I don't know what tool you copied these from where they say "noStandard" - not sure what that means, but I would expect it to be `int(11) unsigned not null` for BOTH columns